# WinSock Library for Visual C++ 2008 Express?

Tags: visual-c++, winsock, visual-c++-2008-express

please how to add winsock library to Visual C++ 2008 Express? I tried including `<windows.h>` alone, than `<windows.h> and <winsock.h>,` but I get LINK error on WSAStartup().

I found somewhere that you need to add additional dependencies for your project, so I brought up linker for project properties, and in the select box for additional dependencies there was no ws_32.lib, So I tried to add it manually (write it) but still LINK Error....

Comment: please post the actual error that you get.

Comment: how sure are u that you actually have the we_32.lib or that it's called that way ? did you try to look in the VS directory for the libs or dlls to see if you got it (i'm pretty sure it's ought to be with the version, since it's pretty basic, non the less, if you don't have the directory it resides in in your -L switch just writing the name will not suffice.

Comment: FYI: The WinSock library is actually `ws2_32.lib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual C++ Express don't install the full Windows SDK.  You can [download and install](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx) the full SDK from Microsoft.

After installing the SDK there is a tool (it will be on the start menu) to register the SDK directories with Visual Studio.  After than you should be able to reference winsock.